# 12.10 error after login -Evolution calendar

Tags: evolution, calendar

Why do I, after having installed Ubuntu 12.10 for nearly 3 months, still every second log-in have this evolution epiphany calendar error. I know more people have this issue.

All upgrades applied, 3 months passed, I'm sending reports every time errors appear and no one can do anything with it there at Canonical?

PS. i read the log that being send to Canonical and theres the following written "*no upgrades applied, probably fresh install*" Which isn't true, because i apply all upgrades available, since fresh install was like 250MB or so. Why isn't this fixed yet?

Comment: I think it is a bug. (but I'm not sure). Try a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I did clean install when 12.10 came out.

Comment: @Mikey he's suggesting a fresh install now, as in remove your current install and re-install, your first clean install might have a persistent bug which will probably be fixed now in the new ISO image you download off the [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: a clean install for this bug is definitely overkill

Comment: Please provide details of the error message you see.

Comment: Then i will have to reboot the system but i already applied the fix from Private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. You can find more on it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-data-server/+bug/1062068).

The solution that the bug report proposes is:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install evolution-data-server indicator-datetime unity-scope-gdocs
```

You can also select the option to no longer report this bug (I think this is in the pop-up).

[image]

Or you could switch of bug reports as such. The latter is a personal choice. You can do it typing `privacy` in the Dash, then look for this screen:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It's clearer now, however i though all bugs can be fixed by updates, but seems i was mistaken.