# Evolution Calendar factory error

Tags: evolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.10 error after login -Evolution calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236487/12-10-error-after-login-evolution-calendar)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and get this error with the Evolution calendar factory. I do not know why I am getting this. The title of the error is:

> evolution-calendar-factory crashed with SIGSEGV in_nptl_deallocate_tsd()

The package name is `evolution-data-servern3.6.0-0ubuntu3`.